# TSLint rule for curly braces after return

Tags: typescript, tslint

Do anybody know how to make TSLint fails in such case?

```
     ↓
return{
    id: this.user.id,
    isAdmin: this.user.isAdmin,
    email: this.profileForm.value.email,
    password: this.profileForm.value.password,
    firstName: this.profileForm.value.firstName,
    secondName: this.profileForm.value.secondName,
    mobilePhone: this.profileForm.value.mobilePhone,
};
```

I have such tslint.json

```
"one-line": [true, "check-open-brace", "check-catch", "check-else", "check-whitespace"],
"whitespace": [true, "check-branch", "check-decl", "check-operator", "check-separator", "check-type"]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: To check if I understand correctly, you want to make it so that you have to assign the object to a variable, then return the variable?

Comment: Sorry for not clear question) No, I want to force to add space between return and curly brace.